# Should disabled elements ever have pointer events?

Tags: forms, buttons, feedback, disable

Modern browsers have a CSS property called `pointer-events` which has a possible value of `none`. This value makes it so that no JavaScript listeners nor CSS pseudo classes fired by events (`:hover`, `:active`, etc.) have an effect.

To me, this makes sense to apply to disabled elements. However, this would mean that disabled elements would never have a different cursor like `not-allowed`.

Should disabled elements ever have pointer events? Or are some pointer events (like changing cursor on hover) useful for disabled elements?

Answer (score 4):

From a UX perspective, there are things that could be done to help the user experience by not setting pointer-events to none.  Showing disabled fields to a person is sometimes cruel.  If the rules for why the field is disabled are complex and not obvious from the screen layout, it is like holding a carrot just out of reach of the person trying to use the system.  I have seen some desktop apps that actually turn on field level help for disabled fields letting you know you have to do to allow the field to be enabled.

A not allowed cursor is probably not very helpful unless it is for a drop target using a drag and drop UI.

Answer (score 2):

**I would not use `pointer-events:none;` on a disabled button.**

It's better to manually set the cursor and hover effect to the default/disabled state.

In some cases it's useful to add a tooltip to a disabled button; pointer-events none would disable this.

I've added a use case for `pointer-events:none;` below if your interested..

**Pointer Event Use Example**

---

It's generally used to allow interaction with elements behind the element it's applied to.

Here's an example I used `pointer-events:none;` on recently.

The magnifying glass icon is over a hyperlinked image, without attaching `pointer-events:none;` to the icon - the user would not fire the link if they clicked the icon.

[image: pointer event example]